# Drupal select box value when submitting the form

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I have the following in the code :

```
$form['location'] = array(
    '#value' => '<select name="location">
                <option value="778">Location1 </option>
                <option value="779">Location2 </option>
                <option value="780">Location3 </option>
                <option value="781">Location4 </option>
                </select>',

 );
```

In the submit function how do I access the value that was selected in the select box?

`$form_state['values']['location']` does not work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you do it in Drupal. Read [this](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6) before trying to create a form in Drupal

That's how a select element should look like:

```
$form['feed'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select', 
      '#title' => t('Display of XML feed items'), 
      '#default_value' => variable_get('feed_item_length','teaser'),
      '#options' => array(
        'title' => t('Titles only'), 
        'teaser' => t('Titles plus teaser'), 
        'fulltext' => t('Full text'),
      ),
      '#description' => t('Global setting for the length of XML feed items that are output by default.'),
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

Above code is perfect and it worked..

Even you can create your From using webform module which is contributed modukes.

http://drupal.org/project/webform